# Who calls fair.c for a process to run on linux?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, scheduler, cfs

Can someone please explain the real call stack of linux for process from creation to scheduling over CPU along with code reference. I don't need theoretical explanation.

I tried reading fair.c but it didn't worked well for me.